# Align radio buttons inside RadioGroup

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have four radio buttons, and I want to align them both horizontally and vertically. I've tried to drag them in AndroidStudio, but it won't let me drag them to the position I want.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/test_activity_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:weightSum="1"
tools:context="com.aruffolo.quiz.TestActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/test_activity_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/test_activity_msg" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/questionText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/test_activity_text"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="86dp"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="500dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:layout_weight=".07"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
    android:layout_below="@+id/questionText">


    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New RadioButton"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>

    <RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New RadioButton"
    android:layout_gravity="right|top"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"    />

    <RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New RadioButton"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New RadioButton"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>

</RadioGroup>
```

Here is how it looks like:[image: layout]

The top and bottom buttons should be aligned horizontally.

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't acheive that because RadioGroup is a child of the LinearLayout Class.
My Solution is to place radioButtons however you want inside RelativeLayout, ConstrainLayout, or nested LinearLayouts..

store the currentChecked RadioButton Id in a field.

```
int currentCheckedRadioButton = 0;
```

store all the radioButtons ids in an int Array field.

```
int[] myRadioButtons= new int[6];
```

and in the onCreate:

```
    //add radioButtons to the array field.
    myRadioButtons[0] = R.id.first;
    myRadioButtons[1] = R.id.second;
    //..
    //add onClickListener for each radioButton.
    for (int radioButtonID : myRadioButtons) {
        findViewById(radioButtonID).setOnClickListener(
                    new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (currentCheckedRadioButton != 0){
                    ((RadioButton) findViewById(currentCheckedRadioButton)).setChecked(false);
                }

                currentCheckedRadioButton = v.getId();

            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

please chenge code like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/test_activity_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:weightSum="1"
    tools:context="com.aruffolo.quiz.TestActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/test_activity_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="test_activity_msg" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/questionText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/test_activity_text"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="86dp"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="500dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_weight=".07"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:layout_below="@+id/questionText">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New RadioButton"

            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New RadioButton"

            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"    />
</LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New RadioButton"

            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New RadioButton"

            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
    </RadioGroup>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: you code works, but now I can select more than one radio button.

Comment: dear if you take radio group you can't select more than one radio button if you want to select more than one radio button take only radio button without radio group

Comment: I was not clear in my first comment. With this code I can select more than one radio button, which is the opposite of what I want. I want the radio group to work as it is intended, but with this code is doesn't.

Answer (score -1):

if you want to select more than one radio button please change like below code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/test_activity_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:weightSum="1"
    tools:context="com.aruffolo.quiz.TestActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/test_activity_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="test_activity_msg" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/questionText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/test_activity_text"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="86dp"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="500dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_weight=".07"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:layout_below="@+id/questionText">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="New RadioButton"

                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="New RadioButton"

                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"    />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="New RadioButton"

                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="New RadioButton"

                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```